# Where's the angular controller defined when using Require?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I'm new to Angular+Require so please bear with me as I couldn't find this information online.

I understand that ng-app is not declared in the html as it's bootstrapped manually, but how is ng-controller used? Or is not used?

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ybs9vbEv5Xu9fPaj21ze?p=info) I have an Angular application that runs under Require, but the $scope fields are not shown, is it because the controller is declared incorrectly?

HTML

```
This is the name: {{name}}
<br>
This is the toggle: {{singleModel}}
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="singleModel" 
     uib-btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">
    Single Toggle
</button>

<script data-main="main" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.9/require.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript - main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        angular: 'https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular',
        uiBootstrap : 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.4.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls',
        app: 'app'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        uiBootstrap: { 
          exports: 'uiBootstrap', 
          deps: ['angular'] 
        },
        'app': ['angular']
    }
});

require(['angular', 'app'], function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

Javascript - app.js

```
define([
  'angular', 
  'uiBootstrap'
], function (angular) {

  var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

  app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.singleModel = 1;
  });

});
```

Comment: you still need `ng-controller` or `ng-route`.  This code doesn't have either, but adding `ng-controller="mainCtrl"` in the body tag is a good place to start.  Require doesn't change how angular works, only how it's bootstrapped.

Comment: thanks, adding ng-controller did the trick, I asked because most examples on the web don't have ng-controller

Comment: it is *possible* that they used a controller defined in `ng-route` (or `ui-router`) instead.  If you are using a router, you shouldn't use `ng-controller`; that could explain why you see examples that don't use it.